# Using Phonegap Build 2.1 with Phonegap Version 2.2

Tags: android, ios, cordova, build, cloud

I have upgraded phonegap version to 2.2 but I checked the build is still 2.1 version. Will there be any issue in upgrade of the project and running the cloud build with the version 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some problems. If they changed anything on how the js calls native functions from version 2.1 to 2.2, wich I believe they did because of the changes on the plugins api, some functions that you might use on your app might not work on 1 or more platforms because of the version difference.

Basically, you would be making calls from the 2.2 js version that the 2.1 native version might not understand. You might need to wait for the update on the cloud build, or revert your project back to 2.1.